# circle object constructor not defined

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, polymorphism

I am trying to make class circle extend the Shape class but keep getting a error from JUnit saying the constructor Circle(Point, int) is undefined how would i define the Circle constructor differently from public Circle(Point[] center, int aradius)?

```
import java.awt.Point;

public abstract class Shape {
private String  name;
private Point[] points;
protected Shape(){};
protected Shape(String aName) {
    name = aName;
}

public final String getName() {
    // TODO Implement method
    return name;
}

protected final void setPoints(Point[] thePoints) {
    points = thePoints;
}

public final Point[] getPoints() {
    // TODO Implement method
    return points;
}

public abstract double getPerimeter();

public static double getDistance(Point one, Point two) {
    double x = one.getX();
    double y = one.getY();
    double x2 = two.getX();
    double y2 = two.getY();
    double x3 = x - x2;
    double y3 = y - y2;
    double ypow = Math.pow(y3, 2);
    double xpow = Math.pow(x3, 2);
    double added = xpow + ypow;
    double distance = Math.sqrt(added);
    return distance;
}
}
```

**Circle.java**

```
import java.awt.Point;

public class Circle extends Shape{

private double radius;

public Circle(Point[] center, int aradius) {

    if(radius < 0){
        radius = 0;
    }
    else{
    radius = aradius;
    }
    this.setPoints(center);
}

@Override
public double getPerimeter() {
    double perim = 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    return perim;
}
  public double getRadius(){
  return radius;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass it a single `Point`, not an array.

```
public Circle(Point center, int aradius)
```